# Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\MethodNotAllowedHttpException laravel 8 error

Tags: php, laravel

I got this error on the live server (after deploying the project).. this error doesn't appeared on the local host
this is the request code:

```
$('#SeekerCommunication_table').Tabledit({
                url:"/update-Communications/action/",
                dataType:'json',
                columns:{
                    identifier : [0, 'ssn'],
                    editable:[
                        [1,'id'],
                        },
                restoreButton:false,
                deleteButton:false,
                onSuccess:function(data, textStatus, jqXHR)
                {
                    if(data.action === 'edit'){
                        $('#SeekerCommListModal').modal('hide');
                    }
                }
            });
```

this is the route<< and it defined as post:

```
  Route::post('/update-Communications/action/',[CommunicationController::class,'action'])->name('UpdateCommunications');
```

error is
message: "The GET method is not supported for this route. Supported methods: POST.",…}
exception: "Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\MethodNotAllowedHttpException"
file: "H:\root\home\irbidchambernew-001\www\epusubdomin\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Routing\AbstractRouteCollection.php"
line: 117
message: "The GET method is not supported for this route. Supported methods: POST."
any help please?

Comment: add method to your request as post because you defined post route but you are making get request

Comment: It appears there's a PR pending which will add the ability to set the HTTP method on edit + delete but has not been merged yet - https://github.com/markcell/jquery-tabledit/pull/64/files

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$('#SeekerCommunication_table').Tabledit({
                url:"/update-Communications/action/",
                editmethod: 'post',  // Make post request like this
                dataType:'json',
                columns:{
                    identifier : [0, 'ssn'],
                    editable:[
                        [1,'id'],
                        },
                restoreButton:false,
                deleteButton:false,
                onSuccess:function(data, textStatus, jqXHR)
                {
                    if(data.action === 'edit'){
                        $('#SeekerCommListModal').modal('hide');
                    }
                }
            });
```

Comment: propably your error will change but this is the answer to your question

Comment: why the error appears only on the live server?? on the localhost works perfectly!!

Comment: If your route definitions are same in server, maybe versions of table edit are not same try to npm update it

Comment: ok,, thanks. I will try to update npm on the server.

Comment: be careful while updating it ! Find only table edit in package.json and only install the version you have same table edit in the local